# Macro to Select/Highlight a cell in a table in OpenOffice and clones

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, openoffice-basic

I am writing a Basic macro in NeoOffice (a mac OO clone) and I want to highlight/select the cell in the table the cursor is in at the time the macro runs.

Google gave me the following related snipset, and it does color the cell, but I want to select/highlight it instead as you would with the mouse. I feel I'm on the right track...

```
Sub selectCell
    Dim the_Cursor   As Object
    Dim the_CurCell   As Object

    the_CurCell=thisComponent.currentSelection(0).cell
    the_Cursor=the_CurCell.CreateTextCursorByRange(the_CurCell.start)
    the_Cursor.GoRight(1, true) 'le curseur recouvre toute la cellule
    the_Cursor.GoLeft(1, true) 'le curseur recouvre toute la cellule

    'the_CurCell.setPropertyValue("BackColor", 16711935) ' Magenta clair / Light Magenta
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

PS:I am running NeoOffice v3.3 which should be based on the same version of OO.

Comment: Your code doesn't run on AOO!  (`.cell` attribute not available)

You are aware you can select a cell by code without invoking the (standard) blue selection highlighting?

What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: Cross posted on Apache OpenOffice forum and answered there  
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=77377

Comment: Yes a View Cursor was the solution. I knew I was close... :)  Care to make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copied answer from
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=77377

```
Sub select_Cell_Texttable
    oTexttables = thiscomponent.texttables
    oTable1 = oTexttables.getByName("Table1")
    ocell = oTable1.getcellbyPosition(0,0)
    'ocell = oTable1.getcellbyName("A1")
    oViewCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ViewCursor
    oViewCursor.gotoRange(ocell,false)
    oViewCursor.goright(1,true)
    oViewCursor.goleft(1,true)
end sub
```